# How to send a form with multiple records and include remote: true in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this form for creating/editing experiences:

```
<%= form_for ([@experience.worker, @experience]) do |f| %>

#Form content

<% end %>
```

I made it this way because workers have many experiences and a experience belongs to only one worker (many-to-one relation) and I need to save the experience record which has a worker_id attribute.

Now, I want to submit this form via javascript so I can use format.js in my controller. But I tried putting the **remote: true** parameter in differents places inside the ( ) and I always get a syntax error. Where should I put it or which is the right way to submit a form like this via js?

Comment: Those parentheses look redundant; try removing them and adding `:remote => true` after the end of the array.

Comment: It was as simple as that! Thank you @ArtOfCode

Comment: No worries, I'll put that in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses you've currently got around the array are redundant. You can remove those. When you've done that, you should add `:remote => true` as another argument just after the array:

```
<%= form_for [@experience.worker, @experience], :remote => true do |f| %>
```